# How to convert recordset.field to a string

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I am currently attempting to compare certain values in a column from a query in access to a vector of strings to look for a match between any two values.

I used recordset.fields("column1") to access specific records from my desired column, but it seems like I am unable to get matches since the values are of different data types.

How do I convert the records from recordset.fields("column1") into a string?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant recordset.fields("column1"), in my post. It's a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working in VBA, surround your value with the CStr() function which will return the value converted to string output.